# setTimeout in a loop, it behaves different than expected

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So I know that setTimeout() function can trigger the function passed in after a certain period of time, but it seems behaving differently in a loop. For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(console.log(i + ', time is: ' + new Date()), 1000);
}
```

The console.log() seems printing out the numbers all at the same time. I do not understand why. Could some of you explain why `setTimeout()` does not work in this loop?

Comment: setTimeout is not a pause, it sets a timeout from now and continues. The way to do this is a recursive function that logs itself and uses settimeout to call itself again, adding one to passed parameter (and remembering to stop recursion when your condition is met.

Comment: The way you've currently written this is equivalent to doing `console.log(i + ', time is: ' + new Date()); setTimeout(undefined, 1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the `console.log` to the `setTimeout`, you call it immediately.

Also, you need to put your `i` in a closure, or else all the calls will log `5`.

Try this:

```
function makelogger(i) {
    return function () {
        console.log(i + ', time is: ' + new Date());
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(makelogger(i), 1000); // or i*1000
}
```

Comment: fwiw it prints the 5 log messages at the same time in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: If you want it to log one every second, replace the `1000` to `i*1000` as I noted in that comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the console function at every second, you need to do something different.

```js
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
    {
      setTimeout( function() 
      {
        document.write(new Date() + "<br />");
      }, (i * 1000));
    }
```

This will show the time in 1 second intervals for a total of 5 times.

Comment: this prints: 5, time is: Fri Dec 12 2014 17:24:52 GMT-0500 (EST)
5, time is: Fri Dec 12 2014 17:24:52 GMT-0500 (EST)
5, time is: Fri Dec 12 2014 17:24:52 GMT-0500 (EST)
5, time is: Fri Dec 12 2014 17:24:52 GMT-0500 (EST)
5, time is: Fri Dec 12 2014 17:24:52 GMT-0500 (EST)

Answer (score 0):

In your `setTimeout` the first parameter should return a function that will be executed later. So you want an expression that will be a function invocation, not the function invocation itself.

Try, as a crude example: (`ttl` is trials to live :)

```
function makelogger(ttl) {
    var msg = ttl + ', time is: ' + new Date();
    console.log(msg);

    if ( ttl > 0 ) {
      setTimeout(function(){return makelogger(ttl-1)}, 1000); 
    }
}
makelogger(5)
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setTimeout) is the full MDN description

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem is wrapping your function into a closure:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
{  
    (function(j)
    {
        setTimeout(function() 
        {
            document.write(j + " - " + new Date() + "<br />");
        }, (j * 1000));
    })(i);      
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can chain your setTimeouts:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1 + ', time is: ' + new Date())
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(2 + ', time is: ' + new Date())
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
```

Or you can you use a function to make it good:

```
times = 5;
timeout(times);

function timeout(times) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(times + ', time is: ' + new Date())
        if(times > 1) {
            setTimeout(timeout(times-1), 1000);
        }
    },1000) 
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the inner setTimeout? you're already doing a setTimeout upfront. (and you passed `timeout` to it incorrectly.)